# How to save power point slide as a 8000 x 4500 pixel image?

Tags: windows-10, images, microsoft-powerpoint, pixels

For example, I have a ppt with a circle on it, nothing fancy.

[image]

I **save** this slide **as** a picture (say png). Then I open up that png file using Windows Paint

[image]
For reason I do not yet understand, it says the image is 1280 x 720 Pixels (visible at the bottom of the above picture)

No where in the PPT have I specified how large this image should be. How does it automatically outputs a picture that so happens to be 1280 x 720?

I am asking because for a while when I saved slides as images, the resulting size was 8000 x 4500. This gave me very high quality pictures. I want to reproduce this effect, but I am at a loss as to how this can be done.

I appreciate if anyone can help!

Comment: 1280x720 looks conspicuously like a screen resolution.  The capture driver for "save as" is probably just using the default resolution without resampling or changing the DPI its recording the picture at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save a slide as JPG/PNG/BMP/etc, it exports at 96dpi, so you get an image size that's the slide width (in inches) times 96. Typical widescreen PPT slide is 13.333 wide, so this fits.

You can use a bit of VBA to arf out a higher resolution image; until recently, even VBA was limited to exporting images 3070 pixels wide, max. But as of Office 2016, you can create considerably higher resolution images.

Example VBA:

```
Sub MongoPNGThing()

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Export Environ("TEMP") & "\" & "MONGO.PNG", "PNG", 8000, 4500
    End With

End Sub
```